# using bibtopic and bibentry together

Tags: bibtex, bibentry

As I understand, the package `bibtopic` redefines (and ignore) the commands `\bibliography` and `\nobibliography`. While the package `bibentry` rely on either commands to load the bibliographic entries and insert them in the document when a `\bibentry` is encountered.

Is there a workaround to make those work together? Currently, all I get is an empty place where the `\bibentry` should appear. Here follows a (kinda) minimal example.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{bibentry}
\usepackage{bibtopic}


\begin{document}
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\nobibliography*

The cloud by NIST~\cite{NISTCloud}. Nice graphic card: \cite{TeslaK40}.

BigData:\\
\bibentry{BigData}

\chapter*{Bibliography}
\begin{btSect}{main}
    \btPrintCited
\end{btSect}

\chapter*{Webography}
\begin{btSect}{web}
    \btPrintCited
\end{btSect}

\bibliography{main}

\end{document}
```

The content of `main.bib`.

```
@article{BigData,
    title={{3D Data Management: Controlling Data Volume, Velocity and Variety}},
    author={Laney, Doug},
    journal={META Group Research Note},
    volume={6},
    year={2001}
}
@article{NISTCloud,
    title={{The NIST Definition of Cloud Computing}},
    author={Mell, Peter and Grance, Tim},
    year={2011},
    publisher={Computer Security Division, Information Technology Laboratory, National Institute of Standards and Technology}
}
```

The content of `web.bib`.

```
@misc{TeslaK40,
    author = {\textsc{nVIDIA}},
    title = {{Tesla K40 and K80 GPU Accelerators for Servers}},
    howpublished = {\url{http://www.nvidia.com/object/tesla-servers.html}}
}
```

And here are the commands I use to compile:

```
pdflatex main
bibtex main1
bibtex main2
pdflatex main
pdflatex main
```

So everything should be compiled correctly.

Comment: Do you have to use bibtex, or are you open minded to use the modern `biblatex` that combines (all?) bib-related packages in one powerful tool.

Comment: @Johannes_B I'm open to alternatives as long as it's worth it and that I don't have large changes to make to my 110 pages PhD thesis. When in doubt, I prefer to stick with the most common tools.

Comment: Basically, you want to have two separate bibliographies depending on the topic (or a keyword), right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you are searching is the powerful `biblatex`, coming with all the utilities you need. I made some minor edits to the example, to keep it up to date. You need to decide, if it is applicable to your own project.

I used `article` in the example to keep everything on one page. Which documentclass you are using doesn't really matter.

[image: celelibiBibTopic]

```
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname-main.bib}
    @article{BigData,
        title={{3D Data Management: Controlling Data Volume, Velocity and Variety}},
        author={Laney, Doug},
        journal={META Group Research Note},
        volume={6},
        year={2001}
    }
    @article{NISTCloud,
        title={{The NIST Definition of Cloud Computing}}, 
        author={Mell, Peter and Grance, Tim},
        year={2011},
        publisher={Computer Security Division, Information Technology Laboratory, National Institute of Standards and Technology}
    }
\end{filecontents*}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname-web.bib}
    @online{TeslaK40,
        author = {\textsc{nVIDIA}},
        title = {{Tesla K40 and K80 GPU Accelerators for Servers}},
        url = {http://www.nvidia.com/object/tesla-servers.html},
    }
\end{filecontents*}
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
%\usepackage{natbib}
%\usepackage{bibentry}
%\usepackage{bibtopic}
\usepackage[natbib=true]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname-main.bib}
\addbibresource{\jobname-web.bib}

\begin{document}

The cloud by NIST~\cite{NISTCloud}. Nice graphic card:
\cite{TeslaK40}.

BigData:\par
\fullcite{BigData}

\printbibliography[title=Bibliography,nottype=online]
\printbibliography[title=Webography,type=online]

\end{document}
```

Comment: I moved to `biblatex`, it's very nice. But it required me more time than I'd have expected to convert my document. For instance, the `bibtex` backend doesn't handle the 3 letters code for the field `month` so I had to switch to `biber`. And *some* `howpublished` of my main bib file had to be converted to `url`. But in the end, it worked and `biblatex` seems a lot nicer than plain old `bibtex`. So... accepted. :)

Comment: @Celelibi Remember when `bibtex` came around. Over the years, people added packages to satisfy their needs. Almost 10 years ago development started on the `biblatex`/`biber` combo. There are many advantages. Changing the appearance for example is a bit time consuming, but doable using just LaTeX macros. No, strange b*ea*st files.